# Adsense working on Mobile but not Working on Desktop?

Tags: adsense

My audience is generally a 60/40 split of Mobile vs Desktop. Yet the majority of advertising revnue comes from mobile. Reviewing my adsense report the impressions are far lower for Desktop platforms. Indeed when I access the site , "autoads" do not work anywhere for the desktop. Yet on a mobile device they work as expected.

[image: Adsense report]

Has anyone experienced this?  An example URL is www.planandshop.uk or www.planandshop.uk/login

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your website and I can see auto inserted ads on login page on both desktop and mobile. The ad usually appears below the login form. In addition on mobile I see a top anchor ad but not on desktop. This is expected as anchor ads currently work only on desktop.

On the login page ad sometime inserted in the middle of the login form between "Please login with your email and password below." and "email" field. That doesn't look very. There are a couple of things you can do:

1. Disable this specific placement: when you login to adsense and go auto ads there is an option to preview placements and disable them.
2. Disable ads on login page entirely. Again, on adsense you can choose pages where ads should be disabled, e.g. `/login`.